# Sticky footer messes up the height of sections

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky footer in a webpage that has section with fixed heights. When I tried this [trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/), I got my sticky footer but the sections weren't showing their fixed height. How do I fix this?

Ps: when I change min-height to height, it fixes the issues for sections height but I get no sticky footer.

```css
html,body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
position:relative;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
margin-bottom:200px;
}

.section1{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:grey;
}

.section2{
width:100%;
height:50%;
background-color:orange;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .wrapper:after {
height:200px ;
}

.site-footer {
    background-color:red ;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
<section class="section1">
<h2>header1</h2>
</section>
<section class="section2"><h2>header2</h2></section>
</main>
<footer class="site-footer">
<p>footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: do you have some sketch of what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to create a one page website like the ones in trello.com. I want my first section to be full screen width/height and my section section with height 50% or so. If I dont use the sticky height trick, it works by setting the height of html,body, wrapper to 100% and then choose a height for a section. Now that I'm using sticky footer tricks, it doesn't show the height I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of percent values, you can use "vh"  values for the sections (1vh = 1% of the viewport height):

```css
html,body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
position:relative;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
margin-bottom:200px;
}

.section1{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background-color:grey;
}

.section2{
width:100%;
height:50vh;
background-color:orange;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .wrapper:after {
height:200px ;
}

.site-footer {
    background-color:red ;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
<section class="section1">
<h2>header1</h2>
</section>
<section class="section2"><h2>header2</h2></section>
</main>
<footer class="site-footer">
<p>footer</p>
</footer>
```